# Place marker on Google Maps API once button is pressed

Tags: android, button, google-maps-api-2, marker

I am new to Android development and I am currently trying to get my app to place a maker on a current location once a button is pressed. @SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
 GoogleMap map;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
.getMap();

map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

map.setPadding(0,200,0,0);

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();

mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

mp.title("my position");

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this by replacing this code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    GoogleMap map;
    Button button;
    MarkerOptions mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setPadding(0,200,0,0);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mp.title("my position");

                map.addMarker(mp);
            }

        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mp = new MarkerOptions();
        mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
        mp.title("my position");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't expect such a quick response. When I enter this code though, Eclipse seems to have an issue with the second curly bracket after map.addMarker(mp);

I'm sure I have the correct amount of closing curly brackets as well.

Comment: button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mp.title("my position");

                map.addMarker(mp);
            }

        });
    }

Answer (score 2):

> At the moment it just drops markers every so often.

=> Because you are calling `map.addMarker(mp);` inside `onLocationChanged()` method.

Comment: Oho you have already give answer. I respect you so much. I read your blog several times. It's my pleasure that I see you here. I vote up your answer . it's my respect.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've made this edit but I'm still have an issue with the second curly bracket after map.addMarker(mp);

Could you help? I can't notice why it is happening.

Comment: Again you forgot to complete the `);` after adding click listener to the button.

Comment: @SatyakiMukherjee Thanks for the kinds words and I am glad to know that you read my blog.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace the code

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();
    mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    mp.title("my position");
    map.addMarker(mp);
}
```

to

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();
    mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
    mp.title("my position");

}
```

I think your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

remove `map.addMarker(mp)` from `onLocationChanged(`) method because it adds marker to the map every time a location change event is triggered.